# Find object in collection with fuzzy matching

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
const collection = [
    {
        name: 'THIS_ITEM',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: false,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: false,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }, {
        name: 'THAT_ITEM',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: false,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: true,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }, {
        name: 'THOSE_ITEMS',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: true,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: null,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }
];
```

… and later an object that looks like this:

```
const condition = {
    oneCondition: true,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: true,
    myCondition: false
};
```

I’m trying to match the `condition` object against the nested `conditions` objects in `collection` to find the one that matches so I can retrieve the `name` property from the matching entry.

The thing that’s throwing me for a loop is the fact that the `conditions` properties can have “fuzzy” values. By that I mean that if any properties in the source `collection` are set to `true` or `false` they MUST match the values in `condition` exactly. But if the property in the source `collection` has a value of `null` it can match *either* `true` or `false`.

**Example:**

These would match:

```
const condition = {
    oneCondition: true,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: true,
    myCondition: false
};

const collection = [
    …
    }, {
        name: 'THOSE_ITEMS',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: true,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: null,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }
];
```

These would not:

```
const condition = {
    oneCondition: true,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: true,
    myCondition: false
};

const collection = [
    …
    }, {
        name: 'THAT_ITEM',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: false,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: true,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }, {
    …
];
```

Any suggestions? I’m using Lodash but can’t seem to imagine any solution without an overly-verbose and nested concoction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the conditions and test against `null` value as wildcard.

```js
var collection = [{ name: 'THIS_ITEM', conditions: { oneCondition: false, anotherCondition: false, yourCondition: false, myCondition: false } }, { name: 'THAT_ITEM', conditions: { oneCondition: false, anotherCondition: false, yourCondition: true, myCondition: false } }, { name: 'THOSE_ITEMS', conditions: { oneCondition: true, anotherCondition: false, yourCondition: null, myCondition: false } }],
    condition = { oneCondition: true, anotherCondition: false, yourCondition: true, myCondition: false },
    result = collection.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(condition).every(k =>
            o.conditions[k] === null || o.conditions[k] === condition[k]
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lodash#filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) with [`lodash#isMatch`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isMatch) and [`lodash#omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omitBy) to match the `condition` against a collection object's condition that doesn't contain any `null` values.

```
const result = _.filter(collection, v => 
  _.isMatch(condition, _.omitBy(v.conditions, _.isNull))
);
```

```js
const collection = [
    {
        name: 'THIS_ITEM',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: false,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: false,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }, {
        name: 'THAT_ITEM',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: false,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: true,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }, {
        name: 'THOSE_ITEMS',
        conditions: {
            oneCondition: true,
            anotherCondition: false,
            yourCondition: null,
            myCondition: false
        }
    }
];

const condition = {
    oneCondition: true,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: true,
    myCondition: false
};

const result = _.filter(collection, v => 
  _.isMatch(condition, _.omitBy(v.conditions, _.isNull))
);


console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collecting using lodash's [`_.isMatchWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isMatchWith):

```js
const condition = {"oneCondition":true,"anotherCondition":false,"yourCondition":true,"myCondition":false};
const collection = [{"name":"1","conditions":{"oneCondition":true,"anotherCondition":false,"yourCondition":true,"myCondition":false}},{"name":"2","conditions":{"oneCondition":true,"anotherCondition":false,"yourCondition":false,"myCondition":false}},{"name":"3","conditions":{"oneCondition":true,"anotherCondition":false,"yourCondition":null,"myCondition":false}}];

const result = collection.filter(({ conditions }) => 
  _.isMatchWith(condition, conditions, (objValue, othValue) => 
    objValue === null || othValue === null || objValue === othValue) // if at least one of the values is null or they are equal
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)
 [***.filter()***](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [**.every()**](https://lodash.com/docs/#every) and [**.isEqual()**](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) methods to loop over the `collection` and filter only items which have the same conditions as your object:

```
_.filter(collection, function(c) {
  return _.every(_.keys(condition), function(currentKey) {
    return c.conditions[currentKey] === null ||
      _.isEqual(c.conditions[currentKey], condition[currentKey]);
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const collection = [{
  name: 'THIS_ITEM',
  conditions: {
    oneCondition: false,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: false,
    myCondition: false
  }
}, {
  name: 'THAT_ITEM',
  conditions: {
    oneCondition: false,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: true,
    myCondition: false
  }
}, {
  name: 'THOSE_ITEMS',
  conditions: {
    oneCondition: true,
    anotherCondition: false,
    yourCondition: null,
    myCondition: false
  }
}];

const condition = {
  oneCondition: true,
  anotherCondition: false,
  yourCondition: true,
  myCondition: false
};




var result = _.filter(collection, function(c) {
  return _.every(_.keys(condition), function(currentKey) {
    return c.conditions[currentKey] === null ||
      _.isEqual(c.conditions[currentKey], condition[currentKey]);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```